# Android: Getting Resource ID before AlertDialog is created and shown?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-alertdialog

I'm currently working on letting a user tap an image that will then display an AlertDialog with a zoomed in version of that image. I'm not too sure if the AlertDialog is the best way to go about this but it's my solution for now.

I'm finding myself struggling getting the Resource ID for an ImageView before I show the alert dialog. Here is the exact piece of code where the error is occurring (The comments are failed fix attempts):

```
mPhotoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(mPhotoView != null){
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();

            dialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.zoomed_image, null)).create();
                  
            //medImg.setImageResource(dialog.getContext().getResources().getLayout(R.layout.zoomed_image).getIdAttributeResourceValue(R.id.ivZoomedImg));
            //ivZoomedImg =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ivZoomedImg);
            //ivZoomedImg = view.findViewById(R.id.ivZoomedImg);
                    

            Bitmap bm = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(mPhotoFile.getPath(), getActivity());

            ivZoomedImg.setImageBitmap(bm); // <- null reference
            dialog.show();
                     
        }
    }
});
```

Specifically, I can't seem to figure out a way to access the `R.id.ivZoomedImg` that should have been instantiated through the LayoutInflator? I'm not even sure if that's possible to be honest, though I don't see why it wouldn't. Does anyone know what would be the best way to go around this?

Some things to note:

`R.layout.zoomed_image` is just an XML layout containing a single ImageView with the id of `R.id.ivZoomedImg`

`mPhotoView` is the image being clicked on to have it displayed bigger

Comment: Not sure, but: ``` LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zoomed_image, null); ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
 dialog.setView(view).create(); imageView.setImage();
 ``` Just try it,  it's not tested

Comment: YOUR MIND!!! That worked, thank you so much @JohnyDeph !

Comment: Post your answer and check it as correct!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix involved simply instantiating an independent View where you can pull the ImageView resource Id from!

Lines of coded added:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zoomed_image, null);
ivZoomedImg = v.findViewById(R.id.ivZoomedImg);
dialog.setView(v).create();
```